# How can I do a fuzzy left join across different reports?

Tags: python, sql, excel

Forgive me as this is probably going to be a crazy basic/broad question for you guys, but I'm extremely new to this role and trying to optimize some processes at work.

Here is the problem that I am trying to solve:

Each week I get two reports from two different companies/systems that have information that I need to left join together into a single document or database. They come in the form of excel files. It is relatively small scale with DocumentA being the left document that only has about 60 lines or so and DocumentB having a few hundred. I started with just doing a powerquery in excel that did a left join and the issue is that there is no consistent key. I have to match them together using a company name that is manually entered by the companies so they have minor differences (ex. Big Company LLC and Big Company, LLC.). I can get it to work on windows since microsoft365 for windows has a feature for doing fuzzy joins, but unfortunately I will be working off of a macbook and won't be able to utilize that. I'm looking for an alternative. Here are two examples of the tables I am trying to join:

Table A:

| Company Name | Stage | Stage Date | Stage Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wallys World | Pending | 2/3/23 | 45 |
| Cameras Plus | Initiated | 2/8/23 | 50. |

Table B:

| Company Name | Date Added | Revenue | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wally's World | 1/8/23 | 1,000,000 | Joe Schmoe |
| Camera Plus | 1/20/23 | 1,500,000 | Jackie Sal. |

I have a somewhat basic understanding of SQL and python so I feel like I can manage a solution utilizing them but I'm a bit overwhelmed with how to start.

My main goals are:

Automate the process - making sure that each time I update or add the newest report that it will merge together automatically showing everything in Table A but joined with any near matches with Table B.

I'd also like to be able to keep track of the stages and stage dates if possible. Whenever it begins the next stage, the current report just replaces the old stage and date with the new stage and the date that it started that stage. I'd like to be able to keep a record of the stages and dates that they started and finished. So when a new report begins with a different stage I'd like to still have record of the old stage and date grouped together with the new.

Any help anyone can offer is greatly appreciated!

I've tried using powerquery which seems like a simple solution for such a small dataset, but the inability to do a fuzzy join is making it difficult. I'm also not positive how I would go about maintaining a record of the stages.

Comment: Have you tried Power Query to do some cleaning process first. You load the file, clean it, then consolidate it.

Comment: I did what I would consider basic cleaning as far as removing duplicates, clearing out unnecessary rows and columns, etc. But I'm not sure of any options to better match the company names when they are manually entered and not consistent or to keep a record of the overwritten cells when we get new reports each week.

Comment: For a small subset of variations, you can have a lookup table, but otherwise, if that is not the case, then try to use the following Add-ins: [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) for example.

Comment: Are you writing that Power Query on Excel for the Mac does not include the `Table.FuzzyJoin`  and `Table.FuzzyNestedJoin` functions?

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks for the advice. That link didn't work for Mac, but I was able to find something similar, maybe the same thing even? It doesn't appear to work with PowerQuery, but the fuzzy lookup I was able to download does work for lookup tables, so I might try going that route.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, for whatever reason the Mac version of excel does not have those functions. I created a document at home that worked using those functions but when I brought it up at the office it no longer worked and it took me a while to figure out it was because I was on a mac at work.